# Transmitting/receiving a bitmap with .NET Sockets C++/CLI

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp, c++-cli

Im programming for my Schoolproject an Internet/Multiplayer based Drawing Game.
So now i need to Program a PictureBox which is always actual with the Servers one.

First of all im using a .net TCP Client and Listener which already works(Im sending and receiving some strings). I have 2 static classes which represents the Server and the client.

My basic idea is to Convert the bmp from the PictureBox in a Byte[] transmitt it with a BinaryReader thru a NetworkStream.

On the Other Side the received Byte[] will be converted back to a bmp and goes into the PictureBox.

### here my are my two Functions:

```
void Server::sendBMP(Bitmap^ bmp){
    array<Byte>^bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(256);
    BinaryWriter^ bw = gcnew BinaryWriter(stream);
    MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream(); 

    bmp->Save(ms,System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageFormat::Bmp); //Conversion from BMP to Byte[]
    bytes = ms->ToArray();  

    bw->Write(bytes);}


Bitmap^ Server::receiveBMP(void){
    array<Byte>^buffer = gcnew array<Byte>(10000);
    BinaryReader^ br = gcnew BinaryReader(stream);
    Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew Bitmap(1500,612);

    buffer = br->ReadBytes(10000);

    MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream(buffer); // Conversion From Byte[] to BMP
    bmp->FromStream(ms);

    return bmp;}
```

Im always getting a "System.ArgumentException" Error.

Im using synchronous TCP sockets. Is this the right Way im doing this?

### Stack trace:

```
Server::receiveBMP() line 105 + 0x8 Bytes  
DrawMyThing::MyForm::streamIMG() line 2774 + 0x6 Bytes
```

line 105:

```
bmp->FromStream(ms);  //From my Server::receiveIMG()
```

line 2774:

```
private: static void streamIMG(void){
            while(1){    
             if(status==1){ //If Server
                     bitmap = Server::receiveBMP(); //line 2774

                 }else{
                     Client::sendBMP(bitmap);
                 }
            }
         }
```

BTW im calling this streamIMG function as a thread:

```
Thread^ imgstreamthread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(MyForm::streamIMG));
             imgstreamthread->Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   buffer = br->ReadBytes(10000);
```

The bug in your code is here.  It should have made you a *little* uncomfortable writing 10000 here.  How did you come up with that?  Why not 20000?   Never use a "magic number" when you write code.  That almost always produces a bug.

So what do you write then?  It cannot be too large, the call will just hang.  It cannot be too small, you won't read enough bytes in the bitmap and your program will fail as you found out.  It must be the **exact** number of bytes in the bitmap.

That's a chicken-and-egg problem, how do you know?  You cannot know, the transmitter has to help.  It has to send the size first:

```
void Server::sendBMP(Bitmap^ bmp){
    //...
    bytes = ms->ToArray();  
    bw->Write(bytes->Length);
    bw->Write(bytes);
}
```

Now it is simple:

```
Bitmap^ Server::receiveBMP(void) {
    BinaryReader^ br = gcnew BinaryReader(stream);
    int length = br->ReadInt32();
    array<Byte>^ buffer = br->ReadBytes(length);
    System::Diagnostics::Debug::Assert(buffer->Length == length);
    MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream(buffer);
    return safe_cast<Bitmap^>(Image::FromStream(ms));
}
```

Comment: thanks. This helped me a lot :) But now im getting an System.ArgumentException in system.drawing.dll Error at  return safe_cast<Bitmap^>(Image::FromStream(ms));. I already tried it with the Bitmap(stream) constructor but i got the same Error. Is it possible that the bitmap need some additional Informations like size and rgbformat?

Comment: I have no theory, don't know anything about *stream*.  Debug it, make sure that *length* matches between the transmitter and receiver and that, when you look in *buffer*, that you see the header of BMP (starts with "BM") and that the array's Length matches *length*.

Comment: The length matches. The Buffer is completly written with "255" for white, because my bmp is at the beginning cleared with white. No Header, just clear rgb data.

Comment: There has to be a header, Image::Save() always writes one.  You are not showing us the code you are really using.

Comment: How do i Format code in the Comments? I debugged it and on the client side which is sending the Header exists. however on the server side, which is receiving the data, the header doesnt exist. I think the server side takes as length a piece of the bitmap data. sometimes the length is -1... i have to wait till the length is transmitted and than sending the actual data. Do you have any idea how im gonna do this?

Comment: @BauerMarius: At this point, you may need to accept Hans' answer and ask a new question.  As for code formatting in comments, the best you can do is stick your code in pairs of ` characters.